# How to use specific fields in my JSON object?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am able to retrieve the JSON object from the server.

**What is the syntax to access a specific field, e.g. "name", "id"?**

In the code below 'result' is the object, so I'm guessing if I want to access the "name" field I need to use something like "result.name" but that isn't working for me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
  $.getJSON("https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.1/summoner/by-name/RiotSchmick?api_key=c65e376c-2824-46e5-a055-125c79965f0a",function(result){

     $.each(result, function(i, field){
             $("div").append(i + ": " + field + " <br>"); 
     });   
  });  
 });
});
```

"$.each" loops through it and outputs it fine, **can you tell me how to have more control over this process so I can output specific fields?**

Here is the output of my "each" if you're interested:

```
 id: 585897 
 name: RiotSchmick 
 profileIconId: 583 
 summonerLevel: 30 
 revisionDate: 1387224878000 
 revisionDateStr: 12/16/2013 08:14 PM UTC
```

Thank you and sorry for the terrible question. I've obviously missed something in the authoritative documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array of interested properties and then iterate over that to display the corresponding values

```
$.getJSON("https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.1/summoner/by-name/RiotSchmick?api_key=c65e376c-2824-46e5-a055-125c79965f0a", function (result) {
    $.each(['id',  'name'], function (i, field) {
        $("div").append(field + ": " + result[field] + " <br>");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VuEWS/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
 var obj = {}, items = {};

 $.each(result, function(i, field){
         obj.i = field;
         items[parseInt(obj.id)] = obj;
 });
```

Output of items (which should let you select each object by a unique identifier, such as its ID):

```
var items = {
    585897: {
         id: '585897',
         name: 'RiotSchmick',
         profileIconId: '583',
         summonerLevel: '30',
         revisionDate: '1387224878000',
         revisionDateStr: '12/16/2013 08:14 PM UTC'
    },
    //another object,
    //another object
}
```

Then, you can select an object as follows

```
 console.log(items[585897]); //{id: 585897... etc.
```

The only big caveat I can think of right now is that if you have two objects with the same ID property, then a later one could override an earlier one.  The principle behind this code here is that each ID property is unique.  That way, you avoid overriding anything inside your 'items' object.